# Fresh rep in history shown twice

Tags: bug, reputation

I just looked at my rep history after receiving an upvote, and the highlighted upvote is listed twice (the count is correct):

[image: bugged view]

After a refresh of the page everything was all right:

[image: after refresh]

It's not a big bug, but it still is one. :)

Comment: I think it is not bug. It's intentionally kept. First to see where reputation changes made. After refreshing it switches to it's question group.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: I disagree with you. If it was a design choice it would be very confusing one: *(1)* Just on the left of `3 events` it says `17 mins ago` and not `10 mins ago`, *(2)* If you sum all the `+10` like one normally would you get more than `40`.